# Should Linux shared memory be declared as volatile?

Tags: c, linux

I want to synchronize some processes by sharing memory and semaphores. Here are some pseudo codes:

```
struct ShareMemType {
    int some info;
    ...
    size_t waiting_count;
    ...
    others
};
void* ptr = share_mem = shmat()
ShareMemType* share_mem_ptr = reinterpret_cast<ShareMemType*>(ptr);
```

Master processor:

```
initialize:
memset(&share_mem_ptr.waiting_count, 0 , sizeof(Simple) - x);

while(share_mem_ptr->waiting_count < n) {
    yield()
}
```

Client processor:

```
++share_mem_ptr->waiting_count;
wait()
```

Should `share_mem_ptr` declare as volatile? And all codes are written in the same file. Is the compiler optimizing `share_mem_ptr->waiting` as a `const` value or `register` value?

Comment: What you want is not possible. Well it will work, but not predictably.

Comment: If you're trying to do IPC, use a proper IPC facility. Don't just bash around in shared memory and hope for the best.

Comment: You tagged this C, but your "pseudo codes" uses `reinterpret_cast<ShareMemType*>`, a C++ construct. Are you asking about C's `volatile` or C++'s?

Comment: Nowadays this needs to be done with a mutex, or with `std::atomic` data types.  You need an understanding of concurrency and data races.  The possibility of the compiler optimizing a variable into a register is the least of your worries.  It's not feasible to explain it all in a single SO post.